# SQL for matching ALL many to one using LIKE (Wordpress custom advanced search)

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have 3 tables, where I want to retrieve the posts that match all the search criteria. The criteria are taxonomies that may have one or many values. For example, look for the posts where the taxonomy "mediums" matches "acrylic" AND "oil"

Here's an example query of what I'd like to do, but it's obviously not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships txrm ON p.ID = txrm.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy txm ON txrm.term_taxonomy_id = txm.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms trm ON txm.term_id = trm.term_id 
WHERE txm.taxonomy= 'mediums' AND ( trm.name LIKE '%Acrylic%' AND trm.name LIKE '%Oil%' ) 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.post_type = 'gallery'
GROUP BY p.ID 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

How do I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone's looking for something similar, this is what I went with, wich works, but I'm not sure how efficient it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT txrm.object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships txrm
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy txm ON txrm.term_taxonomy_id = txm.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms trm ON txm.term_id = trm.term_id
    WHERE txm.taxonomy = 'mediums'
    AND ( trm.name LIKE '%Acrylic%' OR trm.name LIKE '%Oil%' )
    GROUP BY txrm.object_id
    HAVING count(trm.name) = 2
    ) AS trm ON p.ID = trm.object_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.post_type = 'gallery'
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

So the subquery returns a list of post_ids/object_ids that have a count of 2:

```
object_id|term.name
1        |oil
1        |acrylic
2        |oil
```

So in the above, only post 1 has a count of 2, since it matches both oil and acrylic.